# XML Schema - declare <element /> with type=anything

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, dtd

Is there any way in XSD schema to define an element, which can be anything, under any namespace. `xs:anySimpleType` will not allow complex (nested) elements.
`xs:anyType` will try to match with any declared types in xsd.

Is there any way to allow anything in element, with any namespace -

```
<xs:element name="a" type="xs:anything"/>
```

so, element 'a' can be anything like -

```
<a />
```

or

```
<a some_attribute="" />
```

or

```
<a xmlns="some-other-uri">
    <b />
    <c />
</a>
```